# rtk query refetching with different args

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rtk-query

I'm creating a toolbar that'll allow users to filter the data they see that's generated from useGetExpensesQuery(). After they click the filter button, should a new query be run, one looking like this:

```
    getFilteredExpenses: build.query<Expense[], {min:string|undefined, max:string|undefined, category: string|undefined}>({
        query: ({min, max, category}) => `expense/expenses?min=${min}&max=${max}&category=${category}`,
        providesTags: ["Expenses"],
    }),
```

or am I filtering the old query results like so:

```
  const handleFilter = () => {
    console.log(start, end);
    expenses = expenses?.filter((expense) => {
      let date = dayjs(expense.date);
      if (!date.isBefore(start) && !date.isAfter(end)) {
        return date;
      }
    });
  };
```

The old query was simply:

```
    getExpenses: build.query<Expense[], void>({
        query: () => `expense/expenses/`,
        providesTags: ["Expenses"],
    }),
```

I tried filtering the current expenses and I know it fails because the page is still using the old data to display the ui, only the const expense was overwritten but I'm not sure how to fix

Any idea what I should do?

This is my complete parent component in which I house all of the fetched data as well as all state that each child uses:

```
import DashboardBox from "@/components/DashboardBox";
import LineChartComponent from "./LineChartComponent";
import {
  SelectChangeEvent,
  Skeleton,
  Slide,
  Typography,
  useMediaQuery,
} from "@mui/material";
import PieChartComponent from "./PieChartComponent";
import { useGetCategoriesQuery, useGetExpensesQuery } from "@/state/api";
import RadarChartComponent from "./RadarChartComponent";
import Toolbar from "@/components/Toolbar";
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from "dayjs";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { getEarliest, getLatest } from "@/utils/dateFunctions";
import { Category, Expense } from "@/types";

const Row1 = () => {
  const isAboveMediumScreen = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 1200px)");
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetExpensesQuery();
  const { data: categoriesData, isLoading: categoriesLoading } =
    useGetCategoriesQuery();
  const [expenses, setExpenses] = React.useState<Expense[] | undefined>();
  const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState<Category[] | undefined>();
  const [minimum, setMinimum] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(null);
  const [maximum, setMaximum] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(null);
  const [start, setStart] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(null);
  const [end, setEnd] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(null);
  const [category, setCategory] = React.useState<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setExpenses(data);
    setCategories(categoriesData);
    setMinimum(getEarliest(data));
    setMaximum(getLatest(data));
    setStart(getEarliest(data));
    setEnd(getLatest(data));
    setCategory("All categories");
  }, [data]);

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<string>) => {
    setCategory(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleFilter = () => {
    const newExpenses = data?.filter((expense) => {
      let date = dayjs(expense.date);
      if (!date.isBefore(start) && !date.isAfter(end)) {
        return date;
      }
    });

    const newCategories = categoriesData?.map((category) => {
      const newExpenses = category.expenses?.filter((expense) => {
        let date = dayjs(expense.date);
        if (!date.isBefore(start) && !date.isAfter(end)) {
          return date;
        }
      });

      return { ...category, expenses: newExpenses };
    });

    setExpenses(newExpenses);
    setCategories(newCategories);
  };

  if (!expenses) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <DashboardBox gridArea="d">
        <Toolbar
          minimum={minimum}
          maximum={maximum}
          category={category}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          start={start}
          end={end}
          setEnd={setEnd}
          setStart={setStart}
          categories={categories}
          handleFilter={handleFilter}
        />
      </DashboardBox>
      <Slide
        direction="left"
        in={true}
        mountOnEnter
        unmountOnExit
        timeout={2000}
      >
        <DashboardBox
          gridArea="a"
          sx={{
            height: isAboveMediumScreen ? "100%" : "50%",
            overflow: "hidden",
            padding: "20px",
          }}
        >
          {!expenses ? (
            <Skeleton
              variant="rounded"
              height="100%"
              width="100%"
              animation="wave"
            >
              <Typography variant="h1">Log in to continue...</Typography>
            </Skeleton>
          ) : (
            <LineChartComponent expenses={expenses} isLoading={isLoading} />

            // <BarChartComponent />
          )}
        </DashboardBox>
      </Slide>
      <Slide direction="up" in={true} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit timeout={2000}>
        <DashboardBox
          gridArea="b"
          sx={{
            height: isAboveMediumScreen ? "100%" : "50%",
            overflow: "hidden",
            padding: "20px",
          }}
        >
          {!expenses ? (
            <Skeleton
              variant="rounded"
              height="100%"
              width="100%"
              animation="wave"
            />
          ) : (
            <PieChartComponent
              categories={categories}
              categoriesLoading={categoriesLoading}
            />
          )}
        </DashboardBox>
      </Slide>
      <Slide
        direction="down"
        in={true}
        mountOnEnter
        unmountOnExit
        timeout={2000}
      >
        <DashboardBox
          gridArea="c"
          sx={{
            height: isAboveMediumScreen ? "100%" : "50%",
            padding: expenses ? "30px" : "",
            overflow: "hidden",
          }}
        >
          {!expenses ? (
            <Skeleton
              variant="rounded"
              height="100%"
              width="100%"
              animation="wave"
            />
          ) : (
            // <CategoryLineChart />
            <RadarChartComponent
              categories={categories}
              categoriesLoading={categoriesLoading}
            />
          )}
        </DashboardBox>
      </Slide>
      {/* <RadarChartComponent /> */}
    </>
  );
};

export default Row1;
```

As you can see, I have a lot of state (which I thought was the best approach for creating a toolbar which is one of the children). Here's one of the child components (LineChartComponent) which takes in the expenses state:

```
import { useGetExpensesQuery } from "@/state/api";
import { Expense } from "@/types";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import {
  LineChart,
  Line,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  Legend,
} from "recharts";

const monthNames = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December",
];

const LineChartComponent: React.FC<{
  expenses: Expense[];
  isLoading: boolean;
}> = ({ expenses, isLoading }) => {
  const finalDate = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("line chart expenses", expenses);
    const finalDate: { date: string; expenses: number }[] = [];

    if (expenses) {
      const orderedDates = expenses
        .map((expense) => ({
          ...expense,
          date: new Date(expense.date!).getMonth(),
        }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);

      const reduced = orderedDates.reduce(
        (map, { date, price, subCategory, userId, category }) =>
          map.set(date, (map.get(date) ?? 0) + price),
        new Map()
      );

      reduced.forEach((price, date) => {
        finalDate.push({
          expenses: price,
          date: monthNames[date].substring(0, 3),
        });
      });
      return finalDate;
    }
    return [];
  }, [expenses]);

  const renderLegendText = (value: string) => {
    return <span>{value}($)</span>;
  };

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
        }}
      >
        {isLoading ? (
          <Typography variant="h4" sx={{ color: "#12efc8" }}>
            Loading...
          </Typography>
        ) : (
          <LineChart
            width={400}
            height={230}
            data={finalDate}
            margin={{
              // top: 5,
              right: 30,
              // left: 20,
              // bottom: 5,
            }}
          >
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
            <XAxis dataKey="date" />
            <YAxis type="number" domain={["dataMin-100", "dataMax+100"]} />
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend formatter={renderLegendText} />
            <Line type="monotone" dataKey="expenses" stroke="#12efc8" />
          </LineChart>
        )}
      </div>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};

export default LineChartComponent;
```

I'm querying data, then setting all data locally, then running a useEffect to populate expenses because initially data is undefined. Then expenses is being fed to the child etc. Although it works, it's a lot of state and as someone not the best with React, I want to know how to improve performance if possible.

Lastly, here's the toolbar:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Dayjs } from "dayjs";
import { DemoContainer } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/demo";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import CustomDatePicker from "./CustomDatePicker";
import { Button, MenuItem } from "@mui/material";
import { Category } from "@/types";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";

interface ToolbarProps {
  minimum: Dayjs | null;
  maximum: Dayjs | null;
  start: Dayjs | null;
  end: Dayjs | null;
  setStart: (date: Dayjs | null) => void;
  setEnd: (date: Dayjs | null) => void;
  categories: Category[] | undefined;
  category: string;
  handleChange: (event: SelectChangeEvent<string>) => void;
  handleFilter: () => void;
}

const Toolbar: React.FC<ToolbarProps> = ({
  minimum,
  maximum,
  start,
  end,
  setEnd,
  setStart,
  categories,
  handleChange,
  category,
  handleFilter,
}) => {

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        padding: "10px 15px 0px 15px",
        display: "flex",
        width: "100%",
        gap: "10px",
      }}
    >
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <DemoContainer
          components={["DatePicker", "DatePicker"]}
          sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}
        >
          <CustomDatePicker
            minDate={minimum}
            label="Start"
            value={start}
            onChange={(newValue) => setStart(newValue)}
          />
          <CustomDatePicker
            maxDate={maximum}
            label="End"
            value={end}
            onChange={(newValue) => setEnd(newValue)}
          />
        </DemoContainer>
      </LocalizationProvider>
      {/* <SearchBar /> */}
      <Select
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="category"
        defaultValue="All categories"
        sx={{
          flex: 1,
          outline: "none",
          height: "50px",
          marginTop: "9px",
          color: "#12efc8",
          "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
            borderColor: "",
            borderWidth: "1px !important",
          },
          "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
            color: "black",
            scale: "1.5",
          },
        }}
        value={category || "All categories"}
        SelectDisplayProps={{ color: "#12efc8" }}
      >
        <MenuItem key="All" value="All categories">
          All categories
        </MenuItem>
        {categories &&
          categories.map((category) => (
            <MenuItem key={category._id} value={category.name}>
              {category.name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
      </Select>
      <Button
        onClick={handleFilter}
        sx={{
          marginTop: "9px",
          height: "50px",
        }}
      >
        Filter
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Toolbar;
```

Comment: Do you just need to filter what has already been fetched and cached locally? Or do you need to make a new query with filter values in query params? What exactly is the question you have here regarding an issue or problem with your code?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is what is the best approach out of those two options and then the best way to implement. Since yesterday I have created local state from the data I fetched and have been updating that local state based on the filters to avoid more fetches, but it results in lots of state so if there's a better solution, I'd like to know what it is

Comment: That's all rather subjective. If you don't need to make, or want to avoid making, multiple data calls (*presumably for the exact same data*) then caching locally and filtering is IMO the obvious choice. OFC, if the data changes often and is light and the network requests are "cheap" then making the more powerful backend server do all the heavy lifting also makes sense. It's basically what works best for the app's use case.  We don't know what the data looks like and we don't know what any filtering criteria are so we can't make an objective suggestion.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the frontend UI code that is trying to do the filtering as part of a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: Yeah definitely!

Comment: I edited to include more code, although it works now, it's a lot of state and I guess I wanna know if there's a better approach then querying data then setting that data in state and running useEffect to make sure it's defined etc.

Comment: The code you have seems fine to me other than the duplicate `expenses` and `categories` state, which is what could be considered derived state (*derived from the queried `data` and the local filter state values*). The derived filtered state should just be computed and passed to the `LineChartComponent`. You can memoize this value with the `useMemo` hook if necessary. Does this make sense?

Comment: Hmm it makes sense but I don't think I know how to implement it. Are you saying remove the setExpenses and setCategories state?

Comment: Can you add the `Toolbar` component to the post so we can see how the props are used and how the filter states are updated, and when/how `handleFilter` is called to effect the application of the filter values? Also, it looks like only the `start` filter value is used. Can you explain briefly how the filtering should work generally?

Comment: Yup, added! The filtering allows users to set a range for the graphs. So if they were to adjust from jan-march to feb-march and press filter, the graph would display data accordingly. I'm still working on the category functionality but I needed start and end as well as min and max because the start and end fluctuates but the min and max I needed to remain permament for the date components to use the minDate and maxDate prop (as you can imagine, this shouldn't fluctate).

Comment: So the UX you want is to edit/change all the filtering criteria ***then*** click a button to apply them all at once versus editing/changing the filtering criteria and computing the filtered results in "real-time" without the need to click an extra button?

Comment: If the latter is quicker and more performant, then I'd like to implement that, but for now yes, the UI is waiting for a button click

Comment: Just implemented it without the need to click the button, I like this option more but i did use another useEffect that looks for changes to start and end, I'm not sure if two useEffects is good practice

Comment: You can use as many `useEffect` hooks as is necessary.... to the extent of keeping good code readability and maintainability.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the feedback and tips. I'd love to show you the finished product if that's even remotely an option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254542/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-mathew).